# Angular when checkbox is clicked show one element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, angular-ui

If there is a element `test-me` for example which takes `URL` has attribute. That URL attribute should change depending on checkbox. If one checkbox is clicked then url1 should be displayed whereas if 2nd checkbox is clicked then 2nd url should be displayed.

Right now I do it this way,

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="chk1"> Check1
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="chk2"> Check2
<test-me url="url1" ng-show="chk1"></test-me>
<test-me url="url2" ng-show="chk2"></test-me>
```

The problem with above approach is that if I have 10 checkboxes then there will be 10 `test-me` elements. How can I do this the better way so that I supply the URLs in a way depending on the checkbox value or something but there will be more modularity.

Comment: there can only be one input checked at any time?

Comment: is test-me a directive?

Comment: @juvian multiple inputs can be checked

Comment: @Akhlesh yes its a directive

Comment: I don´t understand, you want to have 10 test-me but without having to explicitly put the url as attribute or you want to generate x test-me according to the x checkboxes that are checked?

Comment: I dont want to have 10 test-me's but one test-me to manipulate URL's depending on the checbox checked.

Comment: but what url do you choose if more than 1 is checked?

Comment: its a checkbox and I was thinking of providing the url in the `value` attribute so depending on what is checked, the test-me directive will load that. `test-me` is similar to the google map directive so multiple checkboxes mean multiple urls are loaded on the map.

Comment: How about something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/uqdhy01p/

Comment: In that jsfiddle, I like that although how do I plugin test-me directive there?

Comment: really depends on what your directive does, but you can pass as parameter the checkboxes array and process what you want

Answer (score 0):

You can use a controller variable to store all your checkboxes. So inside your controller use an array to store all models :

```
vm.controllers = [];
```

And on view add them into array :

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="ctrl.checkboxes[0]" />
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="ctrl.checkboxes[1]" />
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="ctrl.checkboxes[2]" />
```

So now on your controller you can access all of them and do any calculations you want and store them on another controller variable eg :

```
vm.url = "http://blablabla";
```

Use that on your view : `{{ctrl.url}}`

Comment: What is `vm` here? If I use your code, it says vm is not defined

Comment: Don't just use my code, but understand how ti works. vm is a variable where i keep this reference inside a controller. ctrl is the same when using ControllerAs syntax which is highly recommended.

Comment: Hi, I'm new to `Angular` so would help if you post a `jsfiddle` or elaborate your answer a bit more. Thanks